# How can we mock internally APIs request by karate?

Tags: automation, karate

My code internally calling an API gateway . Like Code another API gateway which we have no control of requests. Like -

There are 4 different APIs - A, B, C, D

```
I can call only A and B , C and D are called by A internally. How do I mock api B?
```

B is 3rd party API and I want to mock it within my karate script without touching 3rd Party. Kindly help!